# MIPS Aiken to Binary

Tags: loops, math, character-encoding, binary, mips

Below is part of my code being used to convert an Aiken code (ex: 0xDCB43210) to binary (ex: 0x48FF4EA).

```
li $t1, 8 #limit

loop:
srl $t2, $t0, 28
andi $t2, $t2, 0xf #mask

li $t4, 4
slt $t5, $t4, $t2
beq $t5, $zero, skip_sub
sub $t2, $t2, 6

skip_sub:
li $t4, 10
mul $t2, $t2, $t4
add $t0, $t0, $t2

li $t4, 4
sllv $t4, $t4, $t1
srlv $t2, $t0, $t4
andi $t2, $t2, 0xf
add $t0, $t0, $t2

sub $t1, $t1, 1
bnez $t1, loop
```

I'm trying to convert each input from Aiken to binary, but none of the outputs match up with what I'm expecting. I've tried going to others for help, but am still struggling. Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried debugging it?  One approach to debugging is to write the algorithm in a language you know, so that you have something to compare with when you're testing and can see exactly where it goes wrong before getting to the final output.